# How to manage different versions of same iOS apps in app store for different clients

Tags: ios, app-store

We have a browser application and this application is using by different clients. Each client is using separate database and service. Regularly(quarterly) we are releasing the upgrade with enhanced features. But some of the clients may not upgrade to the latest. So different clients are using different versions of our product. There is no issue with this because each clients are using their own Database and service.  Recently we build up a iOS app for the same application. In app store we can upload only the latest version of our app, how the clients in lower version can install respective version of their app? Latest version app may not work with lower version of service and Database

Different clients needs to install different versions of same app from app store.

Comment: It can't be possible to release different versions of the same app on the App Store.  Although it's not a good idea as I think, you can go for releasing a different app for a different purpose on the app store.

Comment: This is possible only till they update the app. You can not release a particular version of App to Particular people. You have to upload 2 apps in different name for different people.

Comment: Shall I download a ipa file in my iPhone and install the same in my device (manually)?

Answer (score 0):

In App Store Connect (where you manage your apps in the App Store), you can choose which versions you want to remain in the App Store after you release a new version. The purpose of this is to allow an older version to be downloaded in case the user have an older device or iOS version that don't support the new app version. - So I guess this feature is not really helping in your case.

1. I would suggest you make the same version for everyone, and then within the App (I assume your clients have a login) based on their user selects what you want to present them. - Connecting to their old database and deactivating the new features as an example. This will also give you the opportunity to showcase that there is new features which they may want to opt-in on.
2. You can release a completely new app for each version. Ex. YourApp 1.0, YourApp 2.0 (This is not uncommon, but it's usually more if the same app is radically changed/improved, and you want the old version to remain for some time until you retire it completely).

Hope this clarifies a bit :)

Comment: If I choose 2nd option then the user needs to install new app each time to get higher version. So upgrade option will not available. Is it possible to up same app  (slight change ) with different name in the app store?

Comment: If I opt 1st option , I can restrict new feature by checking the version. But if there is a fix or enhancement in an existing feature may have issues(which will not support the old service)

Comment: That is correct. There will be no update version in that case, they need to install a new app. There is no such thing as "slight change" as you are referring to. It sounds like a pretty complex system you are having. - I would probably try and go as long as possible with solution 1. and when there is something that simply require a new app version you release a new one and update the old with a popover or something to the users that might want the new app. (With a link to the App Store).

Comment: Is it possible to run one iOS app and that will download a particular ipa file from our server and install the downloaded ipa file

Comment: Nope, absoultely not ;)

Comment: I just want to give a note from my experience trying to deploy an app in a similar situation this year. Option #2 ended up being a headache for us. We were flagged in the App Store review process as "spam" because our versions were too similar. We are still in the market for a good solution. We can't upgrade all of our customers at the same time, its just not feasible due to constraints out of our control.